# Full screen Android app, that cannot be closed

Tags: android, fullscreen, app-startup

I'm working on tracking devices that send it's location on fixed time periods. Instead of offering special hardware, I thought I would make Android app and offer it on cheap devices. Since all would be done on rental basis, I do not want users to do anything else on the phone (make calls, ...). That's why I would like to know, if there is an easy way to create an app, that will start when the phone is turned on, it would run in full screen mode and can not be closed?

Comment: that sounds evil... why would you want to do that?

Comment: For the last part, I believe you can't do so. Even if its possible, the user still has to open the app first for it to attach as a daemon process. Anyway, I sense some sinister plans..

Comment: He's explained his reason - lots of companies need/want to track employees etc. Not something I'd like to happen to me but doesn't mean it's sinister or evil!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to implement it by using [custom homescreen](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Home/index.html)